# How to release reference from the ConcurentQueue for the item dequeued from the concurrent queue with TryDequeue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, concurrency, queue, concurrent-queue

I am using ConcurrentQueue (C#, ASP.NET Core) for holding tasks for the upload of the big files. I have a very big memory consumption even after items are dequeued from the concurrent queue. Items are not cleared from the memory.

I understand behavior of the ConcurrentQueue in ASP.NET Core which is in short: every group of the 32 items in a concurrent queue are saved in a separate segment. References are released for dequeued items only after all items from the particular segment are dequeued, and not after TryDequeue() method is called for a single item. This is a problem in my case because I can have very large amount in the memory if in the worst case 32 items are not cleaned, which are potentially very big zip files. I even don't expect to have more than 32 items in the queue in the same time.

Even I extract files and send them separately, every file/image inside can be also big by itself. The only thing which is good enough for me is to release reference for every dequeued item, without further postponing. Is it possible and how?

I tried to use StrongBox, recommended in some articles:

```
ConcurrentQueue<StrongBox<Func<CancellationToken, Task>>> 
workItems = new ConcurrentQueue<StrongBox<Func<CancellationToken, Task>>>();

// Enqueuing:
this.workItems.Enqueue(new StrongBox<Func<CancellationToken, Task>>(workItem));

// Dequeuing:
workItems.TryDequeue(out var workItem);
return workItem.Value;
```

This was not useful in my case. Memory was not freed. I don't know it my problem is related to the fact that I am sending reference to the function to the queue and it is somehow held in a memory. One of the parameters of this function is a concrete file for upload. Others are just strings.

To conclude, I would like to take care of the memory release for the item, after or during TryDequeue() method is called. Is it possible and how?

Comment: If you indent your lines 4 spaces, the editor treats it like code. I did that. You'll want to edit your question and convert the [] to <>.

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041373/memory-leak-with-concurrentqueue helpful to you? What version of .NET are you running?

Comment: I am using ASP:NET Core 2.2 and as I mentioned I tried suggestion from that post which is related to the StrongBox, but it was not helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the comments on the accepted answer here: [Usage of ConcurrentQueue<StrongBox<T>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612098/usage-of-concurrentqueuestrongboxt).

The idea is that you can null the `Value` property of `StrongBox`. So your code becomes:

```
// Dequeuing:
workItems.TryDequeue(out var workItem);
var returnValue = workItem.Value;
workItem.Value = null; // see below
return returnValue;
```

By setting `workItem.Value = null`, you're removing the reference that the `StrongBox` holds to the item. So once your code is done using it there are no more references to the item and it can be collected. Sure, the queue continues to hold a reference to the `StrongBox`, but that thing is tiny.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. You are right, this is one thing I have to do in my code, but still there is something more. Something is still missing, memory is not released. I don't know if this situation which I have is critical somehow, and this is to actually have functions in a queue (waiting to be executed) with large object as a parameter!?

Comment: I also tried with GC.Collect(); before return. Also not helpful.

Comment: I will accept this answer even I still don't know the root cause of my issue, because with this I should probably remove ConcurrentQueue from the list of suspects.

Comment: Doing a `GC.Collect` before return won't help because you still have a reference to the object (in the `returnValue`). If the memory isn't released, it's because you're still maintaining a reference somewhere, but without more information about your code it's impossible for me to say where.

Answer (score 0):

I handle using the Try..Catch..**Finally** pattern. Using the final pattern to set your variable to null is the way to go. The processing point is returned the **finally** section and you can free unused resources there. I build trading software and it must be clean and memory leak free!!!! Good luck!

```
static public ionDESK.Response.GenericResponse<object> RunScript(StrategyInput e)
    {

        var r = new ionDESK.Response.GenericResponse<object>();
        try
        {
            r = e.ExecuteStrategy();
            return r;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            r.Errors.Add(ex.Message + " ExecuteStrategy " + ex.StackTrace);
            return r;
        }
        finally
        {
            // When it returns...free resource
            r = null;
        }
    }
```